# using Matrix and AlphaImageLoader at the same time

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter

Having an issue with the following IE filters:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix()

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader()
```

I cant get both of them working at the same time on the same element.

If I apply either one of them individually they work, but cant seem to chain these effects?

Has anyone seen this bug before?

What would be the correct syntax?

I have tried several combinations as recommended on SO and the MS reference sites, but none have solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the effects to occur in the order you specify above (`Matrix` then `AlphaImageLoader`), it is not possible.

The `AlphaImageLoader` is a [procedural surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which in [the static filters descriptions such as Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is noted that (emphasis added by me):

> When multiple filters are applied to an object, each filter is process
>   in source order, **with the exception of procedural surfaces, which are
>   computed first**. To emphasize a filter's effect, place it last in
>   source order or on the object's parent. Always place transitions last
>   in source order.

So the `AlphaImageLoader` will always process first, even if it is defined last. If order is not an issue to you (though I suspect it is), then simply this **should work**:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader() progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix();
```

Note the spaces (whitespace) between the `filter` calls. You cannot call it one place and then again in another, as it will overwrite the previous `filter`. **So this does not work** as the second will overwrite the first:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader();
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix();
```